# how to keep a rpm package during system upgrade?

Tags: yum, rpm

I have a custom built rpm package which I installed manually (via rpm -Uvh / or yum localinstall). If I do an upgradee from CentOS5 to CentOS6 this package is removed and, because it missing in the official repo, will be not installed again. This package is compatible with CentOS5/6.

If I install this package manually after the upgrade, the content of its config folder is overwritten by default conf.

I've used google and found some solutions, please review and correct:

to skip removing the package during upgrade:

1. include the package name in /etc/yum/protected.d/protected.conf -
   doesn't work!
2. add "exclude=packagename" in /etc/yum.conf - doesn't work!

to keep previous config:

1. install-options --excludepath

Questions:

1. how to keep this package from being removed?
2. how to keep old package's configuration?
3. why the yum remove an "alien" package in first place?

Comment: How are you performing this upgrade? And what is the package?